# How can I assign space from a logical partition to a primary one (to resize the primary)

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ntfs, gparted

I have the following situation:

[image: situation].

I want to resize the ntfs partition. Specifically I want to add  it 15 GB.
What is the best sequence of steps to do?

The output from `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to add 15 GB to the ntfs partition.

Comment: From where?  You have to have 15gb free to do that.

Comment: From any partition. sda7 or sda5.

Comment: And what about the part "from logical to primary"? Which of your partitions are primary and which are logical? Please post the output of a `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdX` (where X is the letter of your drive - sda, sdb, etc.).

Comment: There are two ntfs partitions, to which one do you want to add the space?  Please edit your question to be specific enough to answer.

Comment: @Avio, that information can be seen in the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the link :P

Comment: I suspect that he wants to resize the Win7 partition. It'll be a loooong run of gparted...

Comment: Please, see the outputs command [link](http://postimage.org/image/rc9gec42f)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your backups of documents and other important files are current. You might make a mistake, or data loss could occur during dynamic partition resizing. Once that's done,  boot from an Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB, select *Try Ubuntu*, and run the GParted Partition Editor.

*Taking space from `/dev/sda7` is the easiest, as it requires a lower number of resize/move operations than taking it from `/dev/sda5`. This, in turn, is because your `/dev/sda7` partition is closer to the beginning (left) boundary of `/dev/sda2` (the extended partition container), and that boundary has to be moved.*

1. Right-click on `/dev/sda7` (your Ubuntu partition, `/`) and click *Resize/Move*. Shrink it from the left--that is, increase the *Free space preceding*.

   Decrease it by however much you want your Windows partition to increase. Please note that you won't necessarily be able to increase your Windows partition by exactly that amount (depending on alignment issues), but it will be pretty close.

   Now there is space between `/dev/sda6` and `/dev/sda7`.
2. Right-click on `/dev/sda6` (your linux-swap partition) and click *Resize/Move*. Slide it as far to the right as possible, so it is once again flush against `/dev/sda7` (or as close as it can be).

   Now there is unallocated space at the very beginning of the extended partition.
3. Right-click on `/dev/sda2` (the extended partition). It's much easier to select this form the list than from the horizontal bar representing your disk. Click *Resize/Move*. Shrink it from the left--that is, increase the *Free space preceding*.

   Now there is unallocated space outside the extended partition, immediately to the right of the Windows partition.
4. This is the moment you've been waiting for. Expand the Windows partition (`/dev/sda1`) to fill that space: Right-click on it, click *Reize/Move*, and expand it on the right--that is, decrease the *Free space following*.
5. Click the check mark to apply your changes, and hope everything works out OK. When that's done, quit GParted.

You won't necessarily have to reinstall Ubuntu's GRUB2 boot loader to the Master Boot Record, but you might as well, as long as you're already booted into the live environment. (Otherwise, you might have to boot back to the live CD/DVD/USB to do it, after discovering that GRUB is not working well enough to boot Ubuntu...or to boot anything.)

Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run these commands to reinstall GRUB2 to the MBR (it's [this technique](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal), but with the correct values for your system filled in):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt    # For other folks: Replace sda7 with your / device.
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
sudo umount /mnt
```

It's theoretically possible that your Windows system will also need to be repaired, but **very unlikely**, because:

- GRUB2 takes care of bootstrapping to the Windows boot loader (which is in the boot sector of its partition, not in the MBR). That's still present and fully intact.

  <sup>That's the real reason the Windows system will almost certainly be fine. Read on, if secondary factors interest you...</sup>
- The Windows partition still begins in the same place on the disk.
- The Windows partition was just expanded to the right, so all its files are in the same place on the disk.
- Some Windows 7 systems have separate partitions for the boot loader (similar to, but not quite the same as, a `/boot` partition on some Ubuntu and other Unix-like systems). Yours does not. So there's nothing external to `sda1` that matters, when it comes to whether or not the Windows system works. GRUB2 passes control to the boot loader in `sda1`, and from there on everything is in the same place it was before.

In the event that your Windows system did stop booting and you had to repair it, you could do it from the recovery console on a Windows install DVD/USB, including a trial DVD/USB.

### But you probably don't need to resize your partitions at all.

Now that I've presented detailed instructions for resizing your partitions, I'd like to suggest an alternative.

I'm guessing you want to expand your Windows primary partition because you need to fit more into folders that are supposed to be located on that partition and not some other partition.

However, you have another NTFS partition (a logical partition, in the extended partition, to the right of Ubuntu's partitions) with plenty of free space.

So you can make [NTFS junctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) in your small-ish Windows partition, with their target folders in the big-ish logical NTFS partiton.

For example, a folder from inside `Program Files` (or even `Program Files` itself!) could be moved off to the bigger NTFS partition, and a junction created in its place, pointing to it on the big partition.

Or take a look at "[How to create and manipulate NTFS junction points](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=205524)," which explains how to use the `linkd` and `delrp` commands to create and destroy junctions. Or you may prefer [the `junction` command, which you can get here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768). (Windows 7 also supports another kind of symbolic link, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) and [`mklink`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).)

NTFS directory junctions are a lot like symbolic links in ext4 and other Unix-style filesystems. But be careful! Directory junctions are parsed like directories, even in situations where *nix symlinks would be parsed like files. For example:

- Deleting a junction, the way you'd delete a file or folder, *deletes what it points to*. (Or at least deletes the *contents* of what it points to.)
- If a directory `C:\foo` contains a directory `qux`, which contains a junction `bar` pointing to `D:\baz`, and you recursively delete `foo` or `qux` (for example, by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>ing the folder in Windows Explorer), `D:\baz` and everything contained within it gets deleted.
- Moving `C:\foo\qux` to `C:\` (so it will be `C:\qux`) *moves `D:\baz` and everything in it from `D:` to `C:`!*

NTFS junctions don't cause problems in Ubuntu. NTFS-3G, Ubuntu's NTFS filesystem driver, is [compatible with them](http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/advanced-ntfs-3g.html) (though they're treated like Unix-style symbolic links, which means they behave a bit differently than on Windows).

For details or advice on creating and managing junctions (or other forms of symbolic links, as were added in Windows 7) *within Windows*, you should ask somewhere Windows is supported, such as [Super User](http://superuser.com). (And, at least in my opinion, you should use Windows to make them if you decide to use them, even if it's theoretically possible to do so in Ubuntu.) *But I wanted to present what may be a good alternative to resizing your partitions.*

Answer (score -2):

### DISCLAIMER

**before proceeding, be prepared to have an unbootable system. Get a `Knoppix`, a Win7 recovery disk and someone that knows how to recover from a broken `Grub2`/Win7 bootloader.**

Ok, here is what should be the simplest solution. Resize `/dev/sda5` to be close to 165Gb. You'll end up with a free 30Gb partition at the end of the disk. There you can copy your primary NTFS partition (`/dev/sda1`) and resize it to fill the empty space.

When `gparted` has finished, hide the first partition (`/dev/sda1`) and update the `grub2` configuration immediately (`sudo update-grub`).

Win7 shouldn't have problems in booting from a logical partition at the end of the disk if `grub2` does it work properly. However Win7 is unpredictable by definition, so be prepared.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "There you can copy your primary NTFS partition"? I should reinstall Win and all copy all my files on the new partition?. Also, how can I  hide the first partition?Excuse me, but I have not very clear this issue.

Comment: No, you just have to tell `gparted` to copy your whole `/dev/sda1` partition where you just created 30Gb of empty space (at the end of the disk, resizing `/dev/sda5`). You don't have to reinstall anything, `gparted` will copy your Win7 installation sector-by-sector. Win7 shouldn't even notice that it has been moved.

Comment: Partitions can be hidden. It's just a flag that tells the OSes and applications not to consider the partition. Just right click on your `/dev/sda1` partition and in the context menu you should see a menu called `flag management` or something like that. There you can find the `hidden` flag.

Comment: There's no reason to suggest Knoppix on an Ubuntu site... just use the Ubuntu cd, also the hidden flag has no effect in Linux.  Both partitions will be seen and this will confuse grub.  Also windows can not boot from a logical partition.

Comment: The hidden flag is for Win7 in fact. And can you explain why two Win7 installation should confuse grub? I suggested Knoppix because I prefer it over the Ubuntu Live CD. Anyone can use whatever tool one deems appropriate. You should be on Ask Different if you believe otherwise.

Comment: @Avio,once everything is done, what do I do with the old partition `sda1`? I will like assign the "free" space to the DATA partition or somthing like that.

Comment: Once everything is ok (you are 100% sure that you are booting the Win7 inside the new partition and it gives no problems) you can safely delete the old partition in `/dev/sda1`. Unfortunately, it won't be so easy to merge the free space again to `/dev/sda5`. What I can suggest is to keep your partition layout as is until you can buy another disk (maybe a SSD). Then you can rearrange your partition taking into account what you learned so far (15gigs for a Win7 partition are just the minimum, etc).